# Ports are blocked even after opening in firewall

Tags: firewall

In my college some ports are blocked by firewall but they opened all ports in one ip after i asked for it but in that ip, i can only access blocked stuff like steam in Saturday, Sunday and Monday, in rest of days i can't. Timing is also fixed in Saturday after 9 am it start working and in Tuesday after 9 am it stop working. I asked about it and they said they have already opened the port in firewall and it should work everyday they also doesn't seem to figure out why this is happening. They've reset it but that also doesn't help, any idea what could be the reason

Comment: Talk to the college tech department.

Comment: @Xavierjazz by "they" i mean clg tech dept

Comment: What ports specifically are you referring to?

Comment: This sounds like something that you can't control, and asking us won't really help. This is an issue with your college's technology department.

Comment: @Richie086 only web ports like 80, 443 are accessible so any other port except these but i just want to use steam so ports required for that

Comment: Yeah you will need to work this out with IT.